# How to Limit DOM interaction to an element and its children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, javascript-framework

I am building a modular framework for a PHP MVC site. I am using jQuery. I have a `registerModule('module_name')` method that when called creates an instance of a module object with this name. These module objects are functions that return an object they are contained within individual script files.

Example of **test_module.js**:

```
core.modoules.test_module = function(sandbox){
  return{
    init : function(){
      
    }
  };
};
```

Within the `registerModule()` method I am handling inheritance and initialization. On initialization, I would like to check the DOM for an element matching this module. For this example, we'd look for a `div` with id `test_module` and I would like to limit any DOM interaction within the `test_module` object to be within that DOM scope. I currently am using jQuery's selectors but have the feeling I may need to write my own DOM wrapper or something. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$() [takes a 2nd parameter](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#expressioncontext) which limits the search scope

```
$(selector, context)
```

which is really the same as

```
$(context).find(selector);
```